# How in type C-< or C-> in Emacs run inside iTerm2 on Mac Sierra

Tags: macos, emacs, terminal, iterm2

[multiple-cursors](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el) demonstrate to configure `C-<` `C->` to do the mark.

However, I can't type those keys into my Emacs, I [googled this issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76591/101540), and suspect those keystrokes are captured by Mac or iTerm itself. I did several tries:

First start emacs in `-q`, and use `C-h k` to check what emacs got, `M-<` works as expected, but when I type `C-<`, emacs only receive `,` I also try this in Terminal.app, it's the same issue.

Could anyone share some experience about how to configure Emacs running inside terminal to solve this?

Some environment:

- iTerm terminal type: xterm-256color

Comment: Sounds like your terminal does not support those keys. Find out what Emacs commands `C-<` and `C->` should be bound to by multiple cursors, and bind those commands to some other keys that your terminal supports.

Comment: @Drew Thanks, I append a answer, it requires key mapping.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who came across this issue, try this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40222318/2163429

I succeed with iTerm2.