# How to Zoom in /out in emacs -nw (command line only) whithout having a numeric keypad (or mouse wheel)?

Tags: emacs, shortcut

I am having trouble finding the shortcut for Zooming (increasing font size) / unZooming (decreasing font size) in emacs. I must add that I am interested in the command-line emacs (i.e. no window, i.e. "-nw" option) only, I don't use the graphical interface.

The Zoom-in command is supposed to be C-x C-+ and the Zoom-out C-x C--, also since I am using a laptop - often without mouse -, I am not interested by a "mouse-wheel up/down" option.

I tried C-x C-+ in two ways:

1. "typing Ctrl then 'x' then Ctrl then key '1' which is the key with
   the '+' symbol above the 1 on my qwertz keyboard"
2. "typing Ctrl then 'x' then Ctrl - WHILE HOLDING SHIFT" then key '1'
   which is the key with the '+' symbol above the 1 on my qwertz
   keyboard"

neither seem to work, although the second would seem to make more sense, i.e. to hold shift as if to write the '+' sign that i can get with shift-'1'

So I wonder: is the shortcut C-x C-+ only intended for people equipped with a numeric keypad ? or is there another way and in any case what do you suggest ?

Comment: No ... the question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660060/how-do-i-bind-c-in-emacs)  that someone linked to this has nothing to do with mine and is formulated so obscurely that I don't even understand what is is about lol

Comment: What does it even mean to "zoom in" within Emacs in a terminal? Are you trying to change the _terminal's_ zoom level?

Comment: yes I m sorry I actually knew the answer but had forgotten - which is very frustrating ! - and some other person reminded me: simply by right clicking on the terminal "header" -> properties then the "font" tab and change font size worked. And finally, i ended up installing a "smarter terminal" for which i simply use the mouse wheel to zoom/unzoom and which manages multiple tabs and different envs (linux (ubuntu/kali etc), DOS, powershell, along each other in different tabs