# How to Zoom in /out in emacs -nw (command line only) whithout having a numeric keypad (also without mouse wheel)?

Tags: terminal, emacs, zooming

I am having trouble finding the shortcut for Zooming (increasing font size) / unZooming (decreasing font size) in emacs. I must add that I am interested in the command-line emacs (i.e. no window, i.e. "-nw" option) only, I don't use the graphical interface.

The Zoom-in command is supposed to be C-x C-+ and the Zoom-out C-x C--, also since I am using a laptop - often without mouse -, I am not interested by a "mouse-wheel up/down" option.

I tried C-x C-+ in two ways:

```
"typing Ctrl then 'x' then Ctrl then key '1' which is the key with the '+' symbol above the 1 on my qwertz keyboard"

"typing Ctrl then 'x' then Ctrl - WHILE HOLDING SHIFT" then key '1' which is the key with the '+' symbol above the 1 on my qwertz
keyboard"
```

neither seem to work, although the second would seem to make more sense, i.e. to hold shift as if to write the '+' sign that i can get with shift-'1'

So I wonder: is the shortcut C-x C-+ only intended for people equipped with a numeric keypad ? or is there another way and in any case what do you suggest ?

And no, this question ([How do I bind C-= in emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660060/how-do-i-bind-c-in-emacs)) ***does not*** answer mine, in fact I *don't even understand what it is about* (question is totally unclear and unrelated to mine - as far as i understand)...

I am just asking how to Zoom/unZoom i.e. increase/decrease font size...

Comment: I took the liberty to repost a similar question since someone who, it seems, did not read my question, mistakenly liked it to this unrelated and unclear question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660060/how-do-i-bind-c-in-emacs

Comment: The point of the duplicate question is that it's impossible to type `C-+` in most terminals, with or without a numpad, so anything you have bound there will not do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since emacs is running within a terminal, you can't directly control the font as you would running as a GUI app. To zoom in and out, you need to use the method that your terminal application provides for changing the font size. This is often <ctrl>+ and <ctrl>-, but your terminal keybindings may be different.